# Input Range with opaque range button isn't working in Chrome but in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input range that is style like a ruler and the range button that is styled as a opaque circle. It's working fine in Firefox and Safari but not in chrome.

I appreciate any suggestions how to make the code work in all browsers.

Here is the code:

```js
obj_sukanya = {
    slidePointPos: function(scope, fval, maxVal, scopeWidth) {
        console.log('scope', scope)
        var figure = fval,
            max = maxVal;
        var h = figure / max * (scopeWidth - scope.next().width()) + 'px';
        scope.next().css({
            left: h
        }).removeClass('hidden');
        scope.next().find('.dynamicVal').html(fval).attr('data-slideval', fval);
        scope.parents('.active').find('.inputbox .amount input').val(fval);   
    },
    bind: function(){
        $(document).on('mousedown', '.pl-amount', function() {
            $('.pl-amount').bind('change mousemove mouseup', function(){
                obj_sukanya.slidePointPos($(this), $(this).val(), 10000000, 696);
            });
        });
    }
    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    obj_sukanya.bind();
        
})
```

```css
.rangelabel {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url(https://img.etimg.com/photo/56312378.cms) no-repeat;
    width: 830px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
input[type=range].pl-amount {
    width: 696px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.rangeval{
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -52px;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 73px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="rangelabel" for="homeLoan1">
  <input max="10000000" min="0" name="points" type="range" class="pl-amount" value="50000" step="50000" id="homeLoan1">
  <span style="left: 123.06px;" class="rangeval"><span data-slideval="2100000" class="dynamicVal">2100000</span></span>
</label>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you create a working code snipper (or add link to your page)? I need to see it in real in Chrome.

Comment: Hi @pavel https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/calculators/home-loan-calculator click on the start button and than click to slider

Comment: Okay, "This feature is currently not available in your region". Sorry, maybe someone else help you :-)

Comment: I also get the error like @pavel - please convert your code snippets to a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code didn't work for me in any browser, i changed it a bit to reproduce the design from your image. I:

- changed the `scopeWidth` in the script a bit and resized the input, both for perfectly fitting to the image and made the input completely opaque
- gave the outer span the same height like its width and 50% border-radius plus boxshadow and made it partially opaque
- gave the outer span a `display: inline-flex` (plus the centering) for aligning the inner span
- defined for the outer span `pointer-events: none` for moving the input without the span as obstacle

With these changes it worked for me in any browser (inkl. firefox)...

**Working example:**

```js
obj_sukanya = {

  slidePointPos: function(scope, fval, maxVal, scopeWidth) {
    var figure = fval,
      max = maxVal;
    var h = figure / max * (scopeWidth - scope.next().width()) + 'px';
    scope.next().css({
      left: h
    }).removeClass('hidden');
    scope.next().find('.dynamicVal').html(fval).attr('data-slideval', fval);
    scope.parents('.active').find('.inputbox .amount input').val(fval);
  },
  bind: function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.pl-amount', function() {
      $('.pl-amount').bind('change mousemove mouseup', function() {
        obj_sukanya.slidePointPos($(this), $(this).val(), 10000000, 672);
      });
    });
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  obj_sukanya.bind();

})
```

```css
.rangelabel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 830px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background: transparent url(https://img.etimg.com/photo/56312378.cms) no-repeat;
}

input[type=range].pl-amount {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
  width: 580px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.rangeval {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 78px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="rangelabel" for="homeLoan1">
  <input id="homeLoan1" class="pl-amount" name="points" type="range" max="10000000" min="0" step="50000" value="50000">
  <span class="rangeval" style="left: 123.06px;">
    <span class="dynamicVal" data-slideval="2100000">2100000</span>
  </span>
</label>
```